# how refocus when insert image in contenteditable DIVs in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, range

There is a div: `<div contenteditable="true"></div>` in IE(7,8,9), then I click a button to insert an image with using the `document.execCommand('insertImage')` method. Then the image was inserted. Until now there is no problem.
But the inserted image is selected with resizable handlers. How could I cancel the selection and refocus behind the image?
Thanks.

`$button.click(function(){
document.execCommand("insertImage",false,'url');
});`

Comment: If you have an ID for the element you wish to focus on, you could just do $("#elementId").focus()

Comment: @ErmSo: I don't think you've read the question correctly.

Comment: Yeah,@Tim Down is right. $.focus method could not solve this. I have tried before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated with simpler code**

Here's some nasty code to do this. In other browsers, it seems to work anyway, so the following can be used as it is.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/mr7Ac/6/

Code:

```
function insertImage() {
    var sel = document.selection;
    if (sel) {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        document.execCommand('insertImage', false, "someimage.png");
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    } else {
        document.execCommand('insertImage', false, "someimage.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks. I have created a Range but I didn't use the select() method to make it focused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (IE only):

```
function insertImage(){
    if(document.selection){
        var sel=document.selection;
        var range=sel.createRange();
        var amount=(document.addEventListener)?2:1;
        document.execCommand('insertImage', false, 'url');
        range.move('character',amount);
        range.select();
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Interesting but hacky, particularly the IE 9 sniff.