# execCommand() to insert image is not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am trying to insert image inside a contenteditable div. Its working in chrome, firefox, opera and safari. But not working in Internet Explorer. I saw this [post](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html#t019), it says `insertImage` works in IE. But I have no idea why its not working here. Will you please help me. Thank you.

html:

```
<button id="btn-insert_image">image</button>

<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
  <p>How does it work? Just put your image size after our URL and you'll get a placeholder.</p>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn-insert_image').click(function() {
    document.execCommand('insertImage', false, 'http://placehold.it/350x150');
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnyvm5x6/)

Comment: And what version of IE [8, 9,10,11,edge]??

Comment: Sorry, mine is verson 11

Comment: Hehe, sorry for lazy anwser, Try to `focus` on element before inserting image

Comment: Does doing what is in this answer make any difference? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329982/how-refocus-when-insert-image-in-contenteditable-divs-in-ie I do not have IE to test at the moment

Comment: @l2aelba Yes I did focus by clicking in the `#content` first.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, its working. But would you please help me understand, I didn't get why does it always goes to else condition where the `var sel` is not required at all?